# Running multiple background processes using daemon thread(C++)

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

In order to run multiple functions using a daemon thread parallelly, I built a queue which holds all the waiting threads. Once a daemon thread finished working on some thread, I pop a thread from the queue and execute him using daemon thread. 
Is there a better way to do it? maby something built-in?

In addition, how do I make my code keep checking if new threads are waiting in the queue(and if daemon thread is finished,immediately pop a new one and start working on it) but meanwhile, execute other functions? (not necessary related to this process)

Comment: So you want a thread, separate from the main thread, that's constantly running, and its job is to execute other threads from a queue? My immediate reaction to this is, have you considered reducing this problem to just a two threaded architecture? One daemon thread is in the background executing *functions* described by a queue, while the main thread can do things in the foreground.

Comment: Meaning, the daemon thread is found in some sort of an endless loop which keep checking if there is a new thread to handle?

Comment: Creating and destroying threads is not a cheap operation. Consider creating a pool of threads that execute functions popped from a queue. And yes, that means that the function executed by each thread is basically a loop